# How to represent floating point numbers using logic gates?

Tags: electrical-engineering, computer-engineering

[image: Question]

Using the formula given at the start of the question, I had to convert the numbers in part (a) to floating point notation.

My answers for part (a) were:
(i) 1111.2^11 + 111
(ii) 1111.2^11 + 000
(iii) 0000.2^00 + 000
(iv) 1100.2^00 + 000
(v) 1010.2^11 + 101

But now i have no clue on what to write for 2(b), because I didn't really use a specific formula for finding out the answers for part (a).
Any help would be greatly

Answer (score 1):

To get the exponent you need to get the index of the highest selected bit of the top 3:

This is the truth table with $B_6$ $B_5$ $B_4$ -> exponent:

```
1** -> 11
01* -> 10
001 -> 01
000 -> 00
```

For the mantissa you shift the bits to the right $E$ bits. The underflow lands in T after a $4 - E$ shift to the right.

Or in other words if $E = 3$ then $M$ will take $B_6$ $B_5$ $B_4$ $B_3$

if $E = 2$ then $M$ will take $B_5$ $B_4$ $B_3$ $B_2$

and so one

$T$ will take whatever bits M didn't take.

Comment: Sorry, could you reclarify the the mantissa bit again? I dont understand what youre saying.

Comment: @james in psuedo code `M = B >> E` and the under flow from that is T shifted by some bits.

Comment: we havent learnt about pseudo code or underflow haha. Could you possibly give an example of what you mean? Thanks

Comment: Could you use one of the examples already given please